# How determine who created a group in SharePoint Online?

Tags: permissions

I wanted to see if there is a way to find out who exactly (what user) created a specific permission group in a SharePoint Online site?

Answer (score 0):

Using UI, it's not possible but we can achieve it using PowerShell script.

When any User/Group is added to SharePoint Site, SharePoint maintain those entries locally in hidden list called `User Information List`. That means whenever SharePoint Group is created in SharePoint Site, it will add one entry to this list and at that time `Author` (`Created By`) field value will be current logged in user.

Below is the PowerShell Script which you can use to get Author value from User Information List for particular group which will give you user who created given Group:

```
Connect-PnPOnline "{Your Site URL}" -Interactive
$context = Get-PnPContext
$group = Get-PnPGroup -Identity "{Your Group Name}"
$web = Get-PnPWeb
$userInformationList = $web.SiteUserInfoList
$groupListItem = $userInformationList.GetItemById($group.Id)
$context.Load($groupListItem)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
$groupCreatedBy = $groupListItem["Author"]
$userGroupCreatedBy = Get-PnPUser -Identity $groupCreatedBy.LookupId
Write-Host "Group Created By Login Name: $($userGroupCreatedBy.LoginName)"
Write-Host "Group Created By Display Name: $($userGroupCreatedBy.Title)"
```

Above script is using `PnP.PowerShell` so you need to install this module first. Please follow [this](https://github.com/pnp/powershell) link to install it.

**Important:** If you receive value for `Author` as `SharePoint App`, that means group is created using some API/Script/Console (Backend) using App Only Context.